# how to start external system application in python specifying startup directory?

Tags: python, windows

For example I know this method: `os.system("cmd")` but it starts console in the directory of the script or in the dir of the interpreter, is there a way to gain control of this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prefered method for subprocess forking is the «subprocess» module.

You can specify a working directory for the command. e.g. :

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call( ['ls'], cwd='/tmp' )
```

See documentation for the subprocess module.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `os.chdir(target_directory)` to change your program's working directory before starting the external application.